# Ubuntu with window manager for longest battery life

Tags: battery, window, mint, fluxbox

I have used Linux Mint mate for a year now and want to try out Ubuntu.

I have a HP touchsmart notebook, 
1.3 Ghz Dual Core
4 GB RAM

But since switching to linux mint from win7 battery life was never as good as in win 7, although I tried different things (eg disabling one of my two graphic cards, etc)

Now I'd like to test some other Ubuntu (derivates).

SHould I even try Ubuntu out, if my goal is long battery life?
Can I just install in ubuntu something like fluxbox to make it more efficient?

Or should I directly go to Lubuntu or something like that.

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Dont bother, use whatever you like.
I tried ubuntu unity, i3, awesome, xfce, kde(on open suse) and they are all basicly the same.

Most of the time you spnd in ONE window, the WM doesnt do anything there and as long as your cpu is fast enough to handle unity nicely (it is improved vastly with 13.04/13.10) or kde they wont make any difference in idle battery usage.

Of course you get a little better battery life with lets say i3, if its what you want go for it or use xfce, i dont like openbox that much anymore since al the hardware is easily fast enough to use xfce on the lowest power consuming state nowadays, my i 3 wont clock up while using unity.

If u want a big impact get tlp and DISABLE THE FRIGGING BLUETOOTH (better:remove the card:D its unsafe, it sucks your power, its slow).